# (R Package 'neuralnet')A quick question: Why the `neuralnet` will produce different result each trial?

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-networks

As I said in title, I don't understand why use the `neuralnet` package to create a regression model will produce different result at each time.

The different results means each time, without modifying any codes, using the `neuralnet` will produce different predictions that I care.

Ex: Assuming I am using `nn = neuralnet(Y ~., data)` to make a neural network regression model. Then, using `compute(nn, test_data)` to find the prediction values. Each time, I will get different prediction values.

Comment: optimization algorithm is stochastic and or minibatch or shuffles on the data and doesn't run until true convergence.

Comment: @TransIndigenous I don't quite understand what you are talking about..

Comment: @nobodyishere then maybe you should extend on your question, making clearer what your current understanding of neural nets is and under which circumstances the random aspect of a neural net is a problem for you and which aspects of "different result" are important for you.

Comment: @Bernhard I just edit it .

Comment: I have voted to reopen. @TransIndigenous got it in the comments. Neural network optimization is numerical and stochastic. (I do wonder if fixing a seed at the beginning will resolve this issue, however.)

Comment: @Dave I tried `set.seed(1)`, not work at all.

Comment: I would have expected that to work, but it could be that something internal to the nnet functions don’t play nice with set.seed. I’ve seen this happen when I’ve done np.random.seed in Python and then run functions from particular packages (none of which come to mind, but I remember it happening and me being surprised). Perhaps nnet has its own way of setting the seed for its functions.